# Want to create column with lists of unique values using groupby and transform

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a sample dataset

```
test = pd.DataFrame({
    'a' : [1, 2, 3]*2,
    'b' : ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b',],
    'c' : [123, 456, 456, 123, 456, 123]
})

print(test)

   a  b    c
0  1  a  123
1  2  a  456
2  3  b  456
3  1  b  123
4  2  b  456
5  3  b  123
```

If I `groupby` columns `'a'` and `'b'` and then try to get a list of unique values (`'c'`) in each group, I don't get the expected results using `transform`

```
# using transform
print(test.groupby([
    'a',
    'b',
]).c.transform(pd.Series.unique))

0    123
1    456
2    456
3    123
4    456
5    123
```

If I use `unique` instead, I **almost** get the expected output:

```
# almost expected output
print(test.groupby([
    'a',
    'b',
]).c.unique())

a  b
1  a         [123]
   b         [123]
2  a         [456]
   b         [456]
3  b    [456, 123]
Name: c, dtype: object
```

What I was hoping for was a `pd.Series` that looks like this using `transform`:

## Expected Output

```
0         [123]
1         [456]
2    [456, 123]
3         [123]
4         [456]
5    [456, 123]
dtype: object
```

I know that I can use `transform` to get the `nunique` values of `'c'` as a series doing this:

```
print(test.groupby([
    'a',
    'b',
]).c.transform(pd.Series.nunique))

0    1
1    1
2    2
3    1
4    1
5    2
Name: c, dtype: int64
```

## Question

Why can't I do something similar with `unique` and `transform`?

#### Side Note

I know that I can do the `groupby` and `unique` and then `reset_index` and `merge` with the original data, but I'm hoping for a more pythonic/pandas-friendly method.

I also tried using `set` and `transform`, but that returned an error.

```
print(test.groupby([
    'a',
    'b',
]).c.transform(set))

TypeError: 'set' type is unordered
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does

```
test.groupby(['a','b'])['c'].transform('unique')
```

work for you?

Output:

```
0         [123]
1         [456]
2    [456, 123]
3         [123]
4         [456]
5    [456, 123]
Name: c, dtype: object
```

Comment: OMG!!! I had no idea that `'unique'` was an acceptable argument! Thank you so much! +1. Can you link to the documentation where you found this? Or did you just know it?

Comment: I can't quite remember any docs mentioning that. Just from my experience, you can `transform`, `apply`, `agg` with names of (most) pandas functions, such as: `mean, sum, min, std,...`. For a list of functions on `groupby`, see [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/groupby.html). Again, most, if not all, functions can be called/applied by their names.

Comment: I knew the common ones (`mean, sum, min, std, ...`) but had no idea that `unique` would be listed. Thank you so much again. Couldn't figure out why `pd.Series.unique` wasn't producing what I wanted.